# I can't seem to be able to pass information to another .php class file from a .php

Tags: php

I want to pass the information from one .php file to another class.php

This is what I have in my main.php

```
<?php
require 'combinations.php';
$string = "12345";
$num = 2;

$c = Combinations($string, $num);

echo $c;
?>
```

I want to pass the $string and the $num which will be changing from my main file to the combinations class.

This is my combinations.php

```
<?php
class Combinations implements Iterator
{
    protected $c = null;
    protected $s = null;
    protected $n = 0;
    protected $k = 0;
    protected $pos = 0;

    function __construct($s, $k) {
        if(is_array($s)) {
            $this->s = array_values($s);
            $this->n = count($this->s);
        } else {
            $this->s = (string) $s;
            $this->n = strlen($this->s);
        }
        $this->k = $k;
        $this->rewind();
    }
    function key() {
        return $this->pos;
    }
    function current() {
        $r = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->k; $i++)
            $r[] = $this->s[$this->c[$i]];
        return is_array($this->s) ? $r : implode('', $r);
    }
    function next() {
        if($this->_next())
            $this->pos++;
        else
            $this->pos = -1;
    }
    function rewind() {
        $this->c = range(0, $this->k);
        $this->pos = 0;
    }
    function valid() {
        return $this->pos >= 0;
    }
    protected function _next() {
        $i = $this->k - 1;
        while ($i >= 0 && $this->c[$i] == $this->n - $this->k + $i)
            $i--;
        if($i < 0)
            return false;
        $this->c[$i]++;
        while($i++ < $this->k - 1)
            $this->c[$i] = $this->c[$i - 1] + 1;
        return true;
    }
}
foreach(new Combinations($string, $num) as $substring)
    echo $substring, ' ';
?>
```

These are the errors I get:

Notice: Undefined variable: string in C:\xampp\htdocs\recSII\combinations.php on line 58
Notice: Undefined variable: num in C:\xampp\htdocs\recSII\combinations.php on line 58
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Combinations() in C:\xampp\htdocs\recSII\main.php on line 6
The fatal error line would be $c = Combinations($string, $num);

Comment: check PHP docs for require() and include()

Comment: (1) remove the foreach loop from your class definition file. (2) change `$c = Combinations($string, $num);`  to `$c = new Combinations($string, $num);` (3) `echo`-ing an object might not do what you expect...

Answer (score 0):

You `require` the file first, before actually defining the variables it uses. Do the `require` *after* defining vars.

That aside, you should generally avoid having "do stuff" code inside a "define a class" file.